# Randomize color scheme

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked around for something that best suits what I want, but I only find specific examples that only cover part of what I want which is:

A randomly selected color scheme that I've preset but not yet coded-- this includes: background images, text colors, and border colors per each scheme.

I have six schemes, and I'd like a theme to be randomly selected when the page loads/refreshes.

Like I've stated, I've found similar examples but only for a background image OR text color.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say you have schemes, do you mean you have CSS already written? To solve this problem will basically just require an additional class or element selector for your whole document, assigned randomly by JS on pageload.

Comment: At the moment, I just have all the colors and images ready to be coded. I didn't know how much coding I'd be doing if I decided to go with this idea, so I decided to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each scheme a CSS file, name them scheme-1.css, scheme-2.css, scheme-3.css, etc.

Then, add this to your html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" id="style-scheme" type="text/css" href="scheme.css"/>
```

Javascript: (assuming use of jquery)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);//number between 1 & 3 (3 stylesheets)

 $("#style-scheme").attr("href", "scheme-" + number + ".css" )

 </script>
```